# Unable to access directory

Tags: filesystems, windows

My XP box indicated that `hal.dll` is missing.  The HAL file was expanded from the XP install disc and saved to the NTFS hard drive. I then booted the machine with sysRescueCD in attempt to move the file to the proper directory: `C:\Windows\system32\`

The NT hard drive was mounted with the `ntfs-3g` command using the force option.  Attempts to access the Windows directory were refused as shown below.  What remedy is available to overcome the I/O error and gain access to `/Windows`?

[image]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsck /dev/sda1
Unsupported: replay_log()
Volume is dirty.
Unsupported: check_volume()
Checking 94160 MFT records.
Unsupported cases found.

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
Please check '/dev/sda1' and the ntfs-3g binary permissions,
and the mounting user ID. More explanation is provided at
http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged
```

Unable to 'force' ntfs-3g, but was able to do so with sysrescueCd.

XP Partition SMART data via Ubuntu Disk diagnostic
[image: XP Partition SMART data via Ubuntu Disk diagnostic]

```
chkdsk C: /r
```

[image]

Comment: what `ntfsck /dev/<node>` says?

Comment: Can you post the last 20-30 lines of `dmesg` or any lines that look relevant?

Comment: @PaulNordin  What relevant tidbits are there in dmesg? pastebin http://pastebin.com/Yiah7HVj

Comment: @Serge : updated question with out of ntfsck

Comment: try "apt-get install ntfs-3g" or "yum install ntfs-3g" to get ntfsck installed. If both fails - download some LiveCD, e.g. with Fedora (https://spins.fedoraproject.org/xfce/download/index.html) and make bootable usb.

Comment: @gatorback Not seeing much. Why did you have to use the force option? What error was given when/if you tried without it?

Comment: @PaulNordin (from memory) attempts to mount without the force option resulted in a message indicating 'unclean' flag requiring force option.

Comment: @gatorback Since you have the Windows XP disc, boot from it and at the option menu, press `R`. This should open a command prompt, which you can then run `chkdsk C: /r`. However, if the problem is your hardware (e.g., failing drive), this could cause more data loss so make sure to back it up first if you haven't already.

Comment: @Serge  I updated the posting: is this adequate (via bootable Ubuntu USB)

Comment: @PaulNordin Thanks for the chkdsk C: / r suggestion: I ran the process and the original symptom persists.  Wondering if there are any other good diagonostics and corresponding rememdies.

Comment: @gatorback You mentioned an Ubuntu live usb. Boot that up and open the `Disks` utility. Select the drive in question. If it says the drive is unhealthy under the `Assessment` field, click the gear icon, select `SMART Data ...` to get an idea why. This will at least help determine if the drive is the problem.

Comment: @PaulNordin Assessment: "Disk is OK, one attribute failed in the past (39 degrees Celcius / 102 degrees celcisus) "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44855/discussion-between-gatorback-and-paul-nordin).